# How can I remove button click effect in Android?

Tags: android, button, onclick

Whenever I click on the button it moves in up direction, Like this
[image]

After filling the whole layout it behaves normally means if then I remove the text and click again it remains on its position
[image]

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blackborder"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b2">

</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b2"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blackborder"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b3"></Button>
```

Comment: Please provide a better explanation - current behavior and expected behavior..

Answer (score 1):

if you mean the shadow effects that appear in onClick event, you can remove it by making your background solid transparent.
like the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke android:color="@android:color/black" android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because I used baseline constraint to connect two button placed next to each other but after removing the baseline constraint I got the desired behavior. Now button is remain on its position after a click.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blackborder"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b2">

</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blackborder"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b3"></Button>
```